# Find the smallest $k$ such that the numbers $a_1,...,a_d$ can be partitioned into $k$ groups where the sum is $\le 1$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find the smallest integer $k$ with the following property: Given
any real numbers $a_1, . . . , a_d$ such that $a_1+ a_2+...+a_d= n$ and $0\le a_i\le 1$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . , d,$ it is possible to partition these numbers into k groups (some of which may be empty) such that the
sum of the numbers in each group is at most $ 1$.

This is from the IMO Shortlist $2013$. I saw the offical solutions but I wonder if there is an approach that goes like this,

First thing we notice is that $d\ge n$, otherwise $a_1+...+a_d\le d<n$ and that $k\le d$. Assume wlog $a_1\le a_2\le ...\le a_d$. Now $n=1$ means $k=1$, if $n=2$ and $d=2$ we get $k=2$, but if $d=3$ $$a_1+a_2+a_3=2$$
Clearly $k\ge  3\implies k=3$ otherwise we can set $a_1=a_2=a_3=2/3$. If $d=4$ We claim $k=3$ Indeed we can assume $a_1+a_2\le 1$ otherwise $$a_3+a_4\ge a_1+a_2>1\implies a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4>2.$$
Hence the partition is $\{a_1,a_2\},\{a_3\},\{a_4\}$.

And I noticed that a similar pattern occurs for $d\ge 5$, namely $$\cases{d=5 \implies \{a_1,a_2\},\{a_3,a_4\},\{a_5\} \\ d=6 \implies \{a_1,a_2\},\{a_3,a_4\},\{a_5,a_6\} \\d=7\implies \{a_1,a_2,a_3\},\{a_4,a_5\},\{a_6,a_7\}}$$
But I can't generalize the partitions but I just noticed that the first set is $a_1,...,a_s$ where $$s=\Bigl\lceil \frac{d}{3}\Bigr\rceil$$
and a possible genralization is $$s=\Bigl\lceil \frac{d}{k}\Bigr\rceil$$
So my question is would this method work? And by this method I mean conjecturing $k=2n-1$ works and proving it using the fact that $a_1\le a_2\le...\le a_d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It holds when $n = 2$ and $d = 4$, but not when $n = 2$ and $d = 5$. If we set $$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) = (0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8),$$ you cannot partition the numbers into $\{a_1, a_2\}, \{a_3, a_4\}, \{a_5\}$ because $a_3 + a_4 = 1.1 > 1$.